# How to fix 'The type name does not exist' error in C# while having the correct namespace and the directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm having an issue trying to build a Project because of the same error result. This error states:

```
The type 'Shared' (my guess the folder) does not exist in the type 'MyNameSpace'.
```

https://ibb.co/fDZ0Pyb - Image of the IDE with error code and the project structure. This image alternative is due to my low rep not letting me post images.

I've tried searching for an answer to solve this issue. All the methods that I tried (for example: excluding the folder and then adding it back, deleting de .vs folder and others) were unsuccessful.

In Blazor the _Imports.razor file has all the files used in the App. In this file, I'm adding the following using statements.

```
@using NeighborHub
@using NeighborHub.Shared
@using NeighborHub.Data
```

I assume that because the folder exists this error should not be popping. If I'm missing anything please help. If this could be recognized as a bug how can I solve this issue or should I open a new issue on github.

POST EDIT
https://ibb.co/sqGyw23 - This image adds more details about the IDE and the error.

Adding to this I'm using .NET Core 3.0 preview 9 which came out not long ago.

The razor page which results in the error is the following:

```
@page "/househubform"
@page "/househubform/{EditId:int}"

@using NeighborHub.Data

@inject Data.ApplicationDbContext db
@inject NavigationManager UriHelper

@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]

<div class="card">
    <h3 class="card-header text-center">Add a New HouseHub</h3>
    //Some Html code

@*--- Code Below ---*@
@code {
    //Variables used to fill the form
    Data.HouseHub houseHub = new Data.HouseHub();
    private string varSurname { get; set; } = null;
    private string varHouseNumber { get; set; } = null;
    private int varHouseholdSize { get; set; } = 0;
    private int FKId { get; set; } = 0;

    //Drowdown list
    private List<Data.NeighborHub> NeighborHub = new List<Data.NeighborHub>();

    //Error Msg
    public string Errmsg { get; set; }

    //Parameters
    [Parameter]
    public int EditId { get; set; } = 0;

    //On change select list update
    private void SelectListUpdate(ChangeEventArgs Event)
    {
        FKId = Int32.Parse(Event.Value.ToString());
    }

    //Submit form to database
    private async Task SubmitForm()
    {
        //Submit logic and validation
    }

    //Edit form to database
    private async Task EditForm()
    {
        //Edit logic and validation
    }

    //Initializing logic using Async Task
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        //If EditId is passed it will start filling the entity to edit
        if (EditId != 0)
        {
            houseHub = await db.DbHouseHubs.FindAsync(EditId);
            //The following will occur only if the entity is found
            if (houseHub != null)
            {
                varSurname = houseHub.Surname;
                varHouseNumber = houseHub.HouseNumber;
                varHouseholdSize = houseHub.HouseholdSize;
                FKId = houseHub.NeighborhubId;
                NeighborHub = db.DbNeighborHubs.ToList();
            }
            //If the entity is not found it will set an error
            else
            {
                Errmsg = "Could not find the entity. Add a new entry or cancel.";
                EditId = 0;
                NeighborHub = db.DbNeighborHubs.ToList();
            }
        }
        //If set to 0 this will create a new entry
        else
        {
            NeighborHub = db.DbNeighborHubs.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is on `MainLayout.razor.g.cs`. I think we need to see that page but I'm not too familiar with razor. It looks like `Shared` might exist but it's not being used properly.

Comment: Until we see the razor page we can't tell for sure.  My guess is though that you may have classes in the shared folder, but none of them actually use it as part of the namespace.  Just because a file exists in a folder doesn't mean it's in that namespace.

Comment: I've updated the code to show the razor form. I'm still prototyping the functionalities in Blazor it looks like a mess, but I can't seem to find the error(my mistake) due to the lack of knowledge I still have in Blazor.

Answer (score 3):

So I traced down the error and it seems that is probably a bug.

Inside the _Imports.razor file I had the following:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using NeighborHub
@using NeighborHub.Shared
@using NeighborHub.Data //Cause of the error
```

So I went ahead and delete

```
@using NeighborHub.Data
```

Somehow this seems to fix everything.
Why? I'm entirely not sure why this @using Namespace.Data statement caused the error.

Comment: had the same problem. That seems to be Blazor glitch, the framework is very unstable

Comment: Just had the problem in .net 8, so the issue hasn't been fixed yet

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I was able to resolve this by removing the solution name from the namespace. For example.

@using NeghborHub.Data

to:

@using Data

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that error message state that *Type* `Shared` does not exists. I can see two novice mistakes which can be here:
- You use @inject NeighborHub
- you forget to add type when declare some variable.